# Como capturar la respuesta json de un iframe con un listener

Tags: php, html5, json

Tengo el siguiente formulario de la pasarela de pago del banco addonpayments. He cargado el contenido en un iframe dentro de un modal. todo funciona correctamente a excepción de la respuesta json del pago. sin utilizar el iframe la respuesta es correcta y es tratada bien. pero al utilizar el iframe el modal se queda en blanco. Addonpayments me recomiendo capturar la respuesta con un evento listener para poder tratarle pero no consigo que funcione.

Código:

```
    <!-- The Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
           <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal body --> 
               <iframe name="hss_iframe" class="iframe_pay"></iframe>
            <form action="https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay" method="POST" name="form_iframe" target="hss_iframe">
              <?php 
                $tf=time();
                $timestampf=(date("Ymdhms",$tf));
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" value="' .htmlspecialchars($timestampf). ' "> ' 
              ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="352109888">
              <input type="hidden" name="ACCOUNT" value="noseguro">
              <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="' .htmlspecialchars($orderId). ' "> '  ?>
              <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="' .htmlspecialchars($precio). ' "> '  ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="EUR">
              <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
              <input type="hidden" name="HPP_VERSION" value="2">
              <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL" value="https://www.4megalon.es/php/finalizarCompra.php">
                
              <input type="hidden" name="HPP_POST_DIMENSIONS" value="https://www.4megalon.es/php/Compra.php">
              <input type="hidden" name="HPP_POST_RESPONSE" value="https://www.4megalon.es/php/finalizarCompra.php">
                <!-- Card Storage Fields -->
              <input type="hidden" name="CARD_STORAGE_ENABLE" value="1">
              <input type="hidden" name="OFFER_SAVE_CARD" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" name="PAYER_EXIST" value="1"> 
                <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="PAYER_REF" value="' .htmlspecialchars($payerref). '"> '  ?>
                <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="PMT_REF" value="' .htmlspecialchars($paymentreference). '"> '  ?>
              <!-- End Card Storage Fields -->
                <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value="' .htmlspecialchars($hashFinal). '"> '  ?>
              <input style="display:none" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Suscribete">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.form_iframe.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Esto `document.form_iframe.submit();` no es un "listener", sino el envío del formulario automáticamente desde que carga la página. De cualquier forma, habría que leer la [documentación](https://desarrolladores.addonpayments.com/#!/) para saber cómo se procesa el formulario y lo que debe devolver.

Comment: me lo devuelve con un json peo no se como hacer el listener para capturar la respuesta